# jquery dialog close not fired

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have defined my dialog on the page load. I can see the dialog and everything seems to be fine so far:

```
dlg1 = $("#modalHolder");
dlg1 = dlg1.dialog({
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        opacity: 0.65
    },
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

Now I would like to set the close event dynamically, so I tried this:

```
function setCloseFunction(fun)
{
    dlg1.dialog({
        close: function(event, ui)
        {
          alert("2");
          fun();
        }
    });
}
```

And I call it as:

```
setCloseFunction(new Function("alert('1')"));
```

However when closing the dialog, the alert never appears. Any ideas?

Comment: You should not use the `Function` constructor to create a function.  Instead, you should write `function() { alert('1'); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the following:

```
dlg1.bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
    alert("2");
    fun();
});

setCloseFunction(function() { alert('1'); });
```

**EDIT**: To remove the function, you can call `unbind('dialogclose')`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used in `setCloseFunction` is only correct when you're initializing a dialog. If the dialog already exists, as in your case, you normally change options like this:

```
dlg1.dialog('option', optionName, value);
```

For events, such as `close`, you bind a listener to it:

```
dlg1.bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: How would I remove the same function now from dialogClose?

Comment: Take a look at the `unbind` function: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind#typefn